# ngb-pagination for angular - How to use only Next and Previous buttons?

Tags: javascript, angular, pagination, ng-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I'm using ngb-pagination for pagination in my angular app and I only need Next and Previous buttons. But ngb-pagination gives me page buttons also. How can I hide those? Anybody have a idea?

```
<ngb-pagination
  [(page)]="page"
  [pageSize]="pageSize"
  [collectionSize]="slotJson.length"
  [maxSize]="1">
  <ng-template ngbPaginationPrevious>Prev</ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbPaginationNext>Next</ng-template>
</ngb-pagination>
```

Comment: you dont want pagination number bar ?

Comment: @aviboy2006 yes.. only next and previous ...

Comment: please feel free to post a feature request https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues

Answer (score 1):

I tried lot to find out option but no success. Customisation you can do to change number to letter. There is option to hide previous and next button but not for page number.

Worse case you can try this :

```css
.page-item{
  display:none;
}
.page-item:nth-child(1){
  display:block;
}
.page-item:last-child{
  display:block;
}
```

inside your `style.css` because `component.css` it will not work.

Here working example :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-ng-bootstrap-simple-pagination-pfv4jx

Comment: If this help answer don't forget to accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the [pagination source code](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/pagination/pagination.ts) I don't see any way to show the prev and next links enabled without page numbers. So, CSS is the only way now.

[image]